# Async and Await with HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, httpwebrequest, async-await

I am trying to use Async and Await when making a web request and am finding that it never gets past the await line.  I am doing this from a Metro app, but I also verified the problem in a winforms app.

```
public async Task<string> DoSomething()
{
    string url = "http://imgur.com/gallery/VcBfl.json";
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

    var ws = await request.GetResponseAsync();

    return ws.ResponseUri.ToString(); ;
}
```

If I don't use await and instead perform a synchronous wait, it works, but I need this to run asynchronously.

What am I missing in this code that is causing the await to never return?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I suspect that further up your call stack, you're either calling `Wait` or `Result` on the returned `Task`. [This will cause a deadlock, as I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Follow these best practices to avoid the deadlock:

1. Don't block on `async` code; use `async` all the way down.
2. In your "library" methods, use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Thank you.  That was exactly it.  Thanks for the link, it is very helpful.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks for the blog posts! Clarifying question: if I use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in my lib (basically a WebClient), can I then use `.Result` when calling it? It seems to work, but I don't know what will happen when I set it loose in the wild.

Comment: @Brad: Yes, as long as the async method you're calling does the same thing. However, it's not a best practice to use `Result`; there are always better options.

Comment: @Stephen, the async method I'm calling returns a Task and does NOT call result. The code in question is a custom wrapper for calling an internal API and the only part I want to make async in the actual GET/POST methods (GetRequestStreamAsync, GetResponseAsync, etc). How do I keep this async without making every method between this and the controller action async and returning a Task? I'd like for the lib to take care of the async nature and the consumer to remain agnostic.

Comment: @Brad: That's not possible, due to the nature of asynchronous code. It's best to use async all the way.