# Await Tasks using Iterators

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, task

I am using the methods described in this article [Await Tasks in C#4 using Iterators](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504197/Await-Tasks-in-Csharp4-using-Iterators) here to replicate using `async` and `await` keywords as closely as possible without C#5.

I've stumbled across a problem which I believe is the same as one that seems to come up commonly when using `GetResponseAsync()` in C#5 [see question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701545/async-and-await-with-httpwebrequest-getresponseasync) as whenever I try to use the equivalent extension method the `yield  return` jumps out of my `IEnumerable<Task>`. I have no `ConfigureAwait(false)` method available though.

Can anyone see a way to solve this?

My code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Processes the image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">
/// the <see cref="T:System.Web.HttpContext">HttpContext</see> 
/// object that provides references to the intrinsic server objects
/// </param>
private /*async*/ void ProcessImageAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    this.ProcessImageAsyncTask(context).ToTask();
}

/// <summary>
/// Processes the image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">
/// the <see cref="T:System.Web.HttpContext">HttpContext</see> 
/// object that provides references to the intrinsic server objects
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="IEnumerable{Task}"/>.
/// </returns>
private IEnumerable<Task> ProcessImageAsyncTask(HttpContext context)
{
    // Code ommited that works out the url
    Uri uri = new Uri(path);

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

    Task<WebResponse> responseTask = webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
   //################################################################//
   //The method appears to be jumping out of the method here on yield
   //################################################################//
    yield return responseTask;

    // Code that runs other tasks

    yield break;
}
```

I'm adding the relevant extension methods as a Github [Gist](https://gist.github.com/JimBobSquarePants/5222741) to make the question more readable.

Comment: Have you considered [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)?

Comment: I hadn't seen it. I was trying to reduce the number of dependencies as it's for a library but I'll certainly check it out.

Comment: If you're using VS2012, `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is the way to go. If you're stuck with VS2010, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the continuation is scheduled using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. It should be fairly simple to add another overload to avoid this:

```
public static Task<TResult> ToTask<TResult>(this IEnumerable<Task> tasks, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
{
    var taskEnumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator();
    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();

    // Clean up the enumerator when the task completes.
    completionSource.Task.ContinueWith(t => taskEnumerator.Dispose(), taskScheduler);

    ToTaskDoOneStep(taskEnumerator, taskScheduler, completionSource, null);
    return completionSource.Task;
}

public static Task<TResult> ToTask<TResult>(this IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    var taskScheduler = SynchronizationContext.Current == null
       ? TaskScheduler.Default 
       : TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    return ToTask<TResult>(tasks, taskScheduler);
}
```

Your code would then call the other overload:

```
private /*async*/ void ProcessImageAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    ProcessImageAsyncTask(context).ToTask(TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```